# A simple AWS Lambda maven project exceeds max size limit?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am having trouble creating a simple Java AWS Lambda that does not exceed the 50MB size limit and I am not sure where I am going wrong...

My actual Java code is only around 100 lines long. I am using Maven to pull in my dependencies, most of which are the AWS dependencies themselves...

After I do a mvn package or mvn clean install the resulting jar is around 64MB!

What am I doing wrong here? If I do not add the AWS dependencies then I cannot build with maven but if I do then the resulting jar file is huge and I am unable to upload it to AWS lambda because of the size restriction...

My pom file is below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>lambda-handler</groupId>
  <artifactId>lambda-handler</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>   
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.166</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.166</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Do not pull in the entire AWS SDK - you've got tons more than you need there.  Start with just pulling in the services you're using - in your example, you're pulling the entire SDK **and** S3.  I assume you just want S3 in that case.  Note that the Lambda events also pulls in a huge amount - do you really need that?  I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458440/use-proguard-for-scala-aws-lambda) and was able to get the deploy size down considerably.

Comment: Thank you! That actually solved my problem and decreased the size of my jar file substantially! Thank you so much! ;)

Answer (score 1):

to fix this issue you need to do the following:

1. Remove the amazon SDK from your pom.
2. Add the Execution Amazon SDK variable:
   AWSEXECUTIONENV -> AWSLambdajava8

Remember to use Java8 in your project. The total size of a simple project will be around 7-10 MB.

If you want to see HOW-TO with github sources and step by step you can see it on my blog:

[jmazzetti.com -> Serverless on AWS Lambda using Java](http://www.jmazzetti.com/serverless-on-aws-lambda-using-java/)

All the best,
Jose.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove `<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>` and `<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>` dependencies from your maven project and update and rebuild your maven project.